# Bitwise Operations on enums having more than 64 values

Tags: cocoa, enums, bit-manipulation

I am new to cocoa and enums , I have more than 64 values in a enum.
 I have to perform bitwise & and OR on it.

For Eg: (Assume that this enum has more than 64 values) 
 enum {
 apple = 0,
 orange,
 pineapple,
 grapes, 
 ..
 ...
 ...
 }

I have a list of items in a dictionary say , Required Fruits = {apple,pineapple}
 I have to get the fruit which is being currently used and check if it appears in the 
 Required Fruits list , say if I have a value apple I have to check if apple is in 
 Required Fruits.

And all this has to be performed using a bitwise operation.
 (apple | pineapple ) & apple

But I have more than 64 values in the enum.
 Can bitwise operation be performed  on enums having more than 64 values ? 
 Please help me on this.Any information on this will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no

Longer answer:

Using enums as bit fields is limited to the largest size of integer available for the underlying type of the enum, and that is typically 64 bits. So you need to consider alternative approaches to implement what you need.

For example: for high-level solutions consider `NSSet`'s of constant strings. For a low-level bit-based solution look at `bitstring` in the C library.

HTH